# Display installed node version on SPA

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to show in my Angular application the version of node installed on the server.
Is it possible ?

For example, on my server, Node `12.0.0` is installed. I want to show this version number as text on a page in my angular SPA.

Thanks,

Comment: Probably it's possible. What did you try? What did you find on a web search? See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a restful service for this.

**in nodejs**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function execute(command, response){
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ 
    response.status(200).json({version: stdout});
});
};

app.get('/version', function (request, response) {
    execute('node -v', response);
});
```

**in angular**

```
 getVersion(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/version')
    .subscribe((resp: any) => {
      console.log('version', resp.version)
    });
  }
```